# Unexpected predictions in h2o.deeplearning

Tags: r, h2o

I'm experimenting with deeplearning binary classifiers using the `h2o` package. When I build a model and then use `h2o.predict` on some new (held-out) dataset, I notice that for some rows, the `Predict` output does not match the value with the highest probability.

Here's a reproducible example, adapted from [h2o's deeplearning tutorial](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/deeplearning/deeplearning.R):

```
library(h2o)

h2o.init(nthreads=-1, max_mem_size="2G")
h2o.removeAll()


df <- h2o.importFile(path = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/master/tutorials/data/covtype.full.csv")

splits <- h2o.splitFrame(df, c(0.6,0.2), seed=1234)
train  <- h2o.assign(splits[[1]], "train.hex") # 60%
valid  <- h2o.assign(splits[[2]], "valid.hex") # 20%
test   <- h2o.assign(splits[[3]], "test.hex")  # 20%

response <- "Cover_Type"
predictors <- setdiff(names(df), response)

train$bin_response <- ifelse(train[,response]=="class_1", 0, 1)
train$bin_response <- as.factor(train$bin_response) ##make categorical

# apply same transforms to test
test$bin_response <- ifelse(test[,response]=="class_1", 0, 1)
test$bin_response <- as.factor(test$bin_response)

dlmodel <- h2o.deeplearning(
  x=predictors,
  y="bin_response", 
  training_frame=train,
  hidden=c(10,10),
  epochs=0.1
  #balance_classes=T    ## enable this for high class imbalance
)

pred <- h2o.predict(dlmodel, test)
```

Now let's manipulate that to bring it into R and add some new columns, using `dplyr` for simplicity:

```
pred_df <- bind_cols(
  select(as.data.frame(test), actual = bin_response),
  as.data.frame(pred)
) %>%
  tbl_df %>%
  mutate(
    derived_predict = factor(as.integer(p1 > p0)),
    match = predict == derived_predict
  )
```

Now I would think the prediction should always match the column with the highest probability, but that's not always the case:

```
> pred_df %>% summarize(sum(match) / n())
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  sum(match)/n()
           <dbl>
1      0.9691755
```

Why isn't that value exactly 1? In my most recent run of the above code, the `p0` and `p1` values are fairly close

```
> pred_df %>% filter(!match)
# A tibble: 3,575 x 6
   actual predict        p0        p1 derived_predict match
   <fctr>  <fctr>     <dbl>     <dbl>          <fctr> <lgl>
1       1       1 0.5226679 0.4773321               0 FALSE
2       0       1 0.5165302 0.4834698               0 FALSE
3       0       1 0.5225683 0.4774317               0 FALSE
4       0       1 0.5120126 0.4879874               0 FALSE
5       1       1 0.5342851 0.4657149               0 FALSE
6       0       1 0.5335089 0.4664911               0 FALSE
7       0       1 0.5182881 0.4817119               0 FALSE
8       0       1 0.5094492 0.4905508               0 FALSE
9       0       1 0.5309947 0.4690053               0 FALSE
10      0       1 0.5234880 0.4765120               0 FALSE
# ... with 3,565 more rows
```

but that still doesn't explain why `h2o.predict` chooses the less probable value.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is this a bug in h2o? Does h2o intentionally use more information in picking a prediction than it presents to me here?

Interestingly, using my `derived_predict` yields slightly higher accuracy, by a hair:

```
> pred_df %>%
+   summarize(
+     original = sum(actual == predict)         / n(),
+     derived  = sum(actual == derived_predict) / n()
+   )
# A tibble: 1 x 2
   original   derived
      <dbl>     <dbl>
1 0.7794946 0.7827452
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. Trying to explain the predicted value versus the p1 value.

H2O uses maximum F1 score by default for classification. With the p1 column you can specify your own threshold.

It is not very obvious from reading the documentation. But you can find it in the R booklet. Strangely enough not in de DRF, GBM, or Deep Learning booklets.

Comment: Awesome! Someone else pointed me to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/TkNkMFprzf0, which is a bit old but I was able to verify that `h2o.find_threshold_by_max_metric(h2o.performance(dlmodel), "f1")` was indeed the threshold that seems to be used